# How do you import btoa in JS?

Tags: json, reactjs, npm

I am trying to access a private JSON file. I have researched that I need to use btoa to provide the user/pass in react js. So far I have used npm to install btoa but I am unsure of how I can import it as it still says 'btoa is not defined'.

I have tried "import * from btoa;" but it has not worked- what would be the correct procedure?

Comment: You don't have to install or import it for code that's running in the browser, it's in the global (window or worker) scope: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the reply, although when I run it an error code of "ReferenceError: btoa is not defined" is given

Comment: Well *are* you running that code in the browser?

Comment: @jonrsharpe well I thought so haha! It is running on an npm server but it is being accessed on the browser. On the browser it gives the error, I did think it was in browser up until about 10 minutes ago